# Tensorboard - pkg_resources has no attribute 'declare_namespace'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorboard

I am trying to run tensorboard but I am getting the following import error;

```
AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'declare_namespace'
```

I have tried reinstalling setuptools and distribute. This is for Python3.5.

Answer (score 2):

This stacktrace is going into the Protobuf codebase so this doesn't look like a bug in TensorFlow. It looks like something is wrong with the setuptools on your system. Maybe try reinstalling it? You can also try installing TensorFlow inside a virtualenv.

See also: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6863